# Firefox or Chrome extension that clicks on webpage links with the keyboard (no mouse involved)

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox, keyboard, vim

I like to use a Firefox extension called [Vimium](https://vimium.github.io/). Basically, it's a way of controlling the browser with the keyboard while mimicking [vim](https://www.vim.org/about.php) shortcuts. However, there's one functionality on it that is not specific from `vim` that works as follows:

[image]

Basically, I press `F` on the keyboard and it'll map all the clickable elements on the page showing a random sequence of two letters on it, so once I type this sequence it'll "click" on that link with the keyboard. I'd like to know other extensions with a functionality like this one. **Does anyone know if this technique for controlling a browser has a specific name or if there are other browser extensions that work like Vimium?**

I'm looking for Vimium alternatives because Vimium shows some bugs while I use it together with some web applications, so I'd like to try new alternatives as this functionality is really useful for me.

Comment: Hi Rafael.  Good question.  Two immediate thoughts: (1) file an issue report on https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues  (2) if you haven't already, you may want to look at https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/vimium-c/ and https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/surfingkeys_ff/   - I hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: I also found https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/modeless-keyboard-navigation/  - It might be worth a quick look as well.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Thanks! So far the Vimium c is the one that worked better for me. It has an easy way to deactivate keys on specific webpages. But inside web applications environments they all still miss some places for clicking... I think their design is more focused on webpages

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to help. Yes, web-apps often use tricks to display content that can confuse extensions unless they are designed to handle the specific cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Vimium C](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/vimium-c/) Web Extension by Dahan Gong has been updated more recently than other similar extensions (it was just updated 4 days ago).

Description from [Mozilla's Firefox Add-ons Site (AMO)](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/vimium-c/):

> Vimium C is an open source browser extension that provides keyboard-based inner-page navigation, browser tab operations, and an enhanced search panel, so you may take full advantages of your browser without a mouse or touchpad.

The source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/gdh1995/vimium-c).  Any issues can be reported there as well.  Currently, the developer is very active in responding to issues.

Comment: Wow this was a latent need that could be of big use to me.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Happy to help!

Comment: I'm starting to use this and I find it more useful than vim itself :)) Anyone who likes keyboard shortcuts needs to do themselves a favor and install this extension.